# How to pick json playload from external file in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How to pick json playload from external file in jmeter?

I Want to login with multiple users for that I need to add Json request. I need to pick json parameter/Json request from external file. Please let me know the process so that i can pick json parameter from external file.

**Json request for example**

{"username":"honey@est.com","password":"Phone@123","provider":"","access_token":""}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to read a single line from a file - go for [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)
2. If you want to read entire file - go for [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)
3. If you have a folder with multiple JSON files and would like to iterate all of them - check out [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter/)
4. It's also possible to read a file using JMeter's [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

   [image]

   this way you will be able to use [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract partial data if needed.